# Allegro, outputting mouse click

Tags: c++, click, mouse, coordinates, allegro

I want to print out the coordinates of my mouse in the graphical window, and when the user clicks it, there should appear a message "clicked". But the problem is when the user does click it, instead of 1 message, I get around 5-10 messages. I understand it's probably because of how fast I release the button. Is there a way to print just one time?

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    install_mouse();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0);

    BITMAP *pic = load_bitmap("mouse.bmp",NULL);
    BITMAP *buffer = create_bitmap(640,480);

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    while(!key[KEY_ESC]){
        blit(buffer, screen, 0,0,0,0, buffer->w,buffer->h);

        draw_sprite(buffer, pic, mouse_x, mouse_y);
        blit(buffer, screen, 0,0,0,0, buffer->w, buffer->h);
        clear_bitmap(buffer);

        if(mouse_x!=x && mouse_y!=y){
            std::cout<<mouse_x<<":"<<mouse_y<<std::endl;
        }
        if(mouse_b&1){
            std::cout<<std::endl<<">>CLICKED<<"<<std::endl;
        }

        x=mouse_x, y=mouse_y;
    }

    destroy_bitmap(pic);
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `mouse_b` hold the state of the mouse? If so it could be outputing the messages once every frame for however long your mouse is down.

Similar to how you handle `x`,`y` store the previous state of the button and only send a message if the state changes, this should give you just 1 message.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use allegro events. [Here is how allegro wiki explains events](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Basic_Keyboard_Example).

The following code would accomplish your task.

```
  if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN) {
      std::cout<<std::endl<<">>CLICKED<<"<<std::endl;    
  }
  else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES ||
          ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_ENTER_DISPLAY) { 
        std::cout<<mouse_x<<":"<<mouse_y<<std::endl;
  }
```